# Your app is vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: google-play-console, android-security

I published an app to the Google Play store. I just received an email from Google that says that "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article. "

I have looked into the google help center article but couldn't find anything that I can incorporate in my app.

Although, I am using Google Play Services SMS Retriever Auth which may be the cause of this problem. I am protecting the broadcast receiver with the SEND_PERMISSION which ensures that an Intent comes from Play Services by doing so:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.SmsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How can I solve this problem? Is anyone facing the same issue? If so please can you guide me as I have to resolve this issue before 20th December or my app will get removed?

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issues. Have you solve this issue?

Comment: @Izzuddiin Are you using the Google Play Services SMS Retriever Auth?

Comment: Nope, I am not.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace (android:exported="true") to (android:exported="false")..

and search everywhere if you are passing any Parcelable Object and try to remove them and check again..

Finally,,,

I recommend to use this to retrieve ur SMS >> [SMS_RETRIEVER_API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request)

Comment: That's helpful!